# increase keyboard height by setting XML dimen variables dynamically

Tags: height, key, android-softkeyboard

> Hi i am **working on soft keyboard** where i need to **set height** of
>   keyboard **dynamically**. My normal **keyboard view before increasing height** is
>   like shown below,

[image]

> So as per requirement **user can increase height of keys** so after
>   setting key's height dynamically keyboard look like shown below,

[image]

> To **increase height** of keys i **used below code**,

```
List<Key> keys = myKeyboard.getKeys();
    for(Key key: keys) 
      key.height = 80;
```

> But as we see in above last image after increasing height of **key's**,
>   they are **overlapping** on each other except to increase height of
>   keyboard,

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="50dip">
```

> As shown in above xml code at **starting key height is 50dip**, then i am
>   **changing it dynamically to 80dip** and it is successfully applying to
>   key's. On the other hand **if hardcoded key height to 80dip**.

```
android:keyHeight="80dip"
```

> It is successfully applying like shown below,

[image]

> So where i am going wrong. Is there **any other way to increase keyboard
>   height dynamically**.

Comment: I've posted my solution (sorry I didn't notice this post is using XML way instead of code way) is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20584529/1241783