# how to increase keyboard height in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-keypad

In my activity, I want to increase the height of the keyboard, not the space between keys.

I have tried few things so far.

First, created a keyboard view in XML file.

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

And called the same thing in java code

```
 mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(true);

public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
    mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);
}

public void showCustomKeyboard(View v) {
    mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
    if (v != null)
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
    return mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
```

It was not working and I tried with another example

[tried link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084235/how-to-change-a-soft-keyboards-height-at-run-time) its also not working

I have gone through the android developer site link and I found one method in keyboard view

```
public Keyboard (Context context, int xmlLayoutResId, int modeId, int width, int height)
```

[Ref link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html)

Could anyone help me solve this problem? How to increase the size of keyboard height.